# Preconditioning and effects on precision of solution of LSE

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

In my courses on numerical analysis I have been tought that the main and principle motivation for preconditioning linear systems of equations is to increase the convergence rate of iterative solvers for that LSE.

But is there any effect on the precision of the computed solution?

I can remember a result on the precision of computed solution of Gaussian elemination, which can be found in "Matrix computations" by Golub and Van Loan (pp.122). The condition number (with respect to some particular norm) does indeed affect the precision of the numerical solution computed by that algorithm.

One might expect, that something similar holds for solutions obtained by, e.g., Conjugate Gradients. This might also affect the stopping criterion.